# Javascript does not run without this broken component

Tags: javascript

When setting this up I did not initially notice that the third `var` declaration had an incorrect method call. The page functioned as I hoped and all was well.

Later I noticed that there was an error clocked in the inspector. I take out the offending line and all should be good- but the script does not work anymore. Strange. So I fix it and change `getElementId('close')` to the correct `getElementById('close')` and it the script as a whole still does not work.

This indicates that the script needs the broken component to properly function.

Be aware that the part that does not work anymore is `openModal()`. The `audio.setAttribute()` and `audio.play()` are in the same block and still work, so that is good. 
I do not actually need a var `close` since the `closeFunc()` is called automatically onclick.

My html:

```
    <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
        <div id='modal-content'>
            <span onclick='closeFunc()' id='close'>close x</span>
            <object id='pdf-enter' data='' type='application/pdf'><p id='fallback-text'>Your browser does not support this media. You can download it <a id='dl-link' href=''>here.</p></a></object>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='aud'>
        <audio id='paudio' src='../../music/Available Now.mp3' controls='controls' preload="metadata">Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code>element.</audio>
        <p id='audio-metadata'></p>
    </div>

    . . . 

    <li><a href='#0' class='title'>Sassthefrass <i onclick='audiosass()' class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-fw" aria-label='Listen to music.'></i> <i onclick='openModal(), sass()' class='fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-fw' aria-label='View the sheet music.'></i></a>
    </li>
```

and the javascript

```
<script defer async>

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var here = document.getElementById('dl-link');
var close = document.getElementId('close');
var pdf = document.getElementById('pdf-enter');

function openModal() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}    

function sass() {
    pdf.setAttribute('data', '../../scores/Sassthefrass Perusal.pdf');
    here.setAttribute('href', '../../scores/Sassthefrass Perusal.pdf');
}

function closeFunc() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

When correctly working, clicking on the pdf FA icon opens a modal with a pdf showing the sheet music. When the code is 'error free', it does not do this anymore.

This is a reduced version, but you can see the entire thing in action at [cortlandmahoney.com/pages/comp/acoustic.html](http://cortlandmahoney.com/pages/comp/acoustic.html). Be aware the site is still in development, but is near completion.

Comment: What's reported in the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

`Close` is not defined as an ID.
You have to define as 'close x'
and at your javascript you can assign function like :

```
document.getElementById('foo').onclick=function(){
alert("You have clicked close");
};
```

I looked at your website link and there is one more exception regarding jquery.
In jquery you have to define as `$('#id').onclick()` function to assign onclick function.

Comment: That was a transcription error. The linked page shows that close is defined as an ID for the appropriate element. The above code has been updated.

Comment: You have to hide like this `document.getElementById('close').onclick=function(){document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none';};`. I have tested this on chrome console.

Comment: You have to hide like this `document.getElementById('close').onclick=function(){document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none';};` and to open it again(to call openModal) `onClick="openModal();openSomething();"`. I have tested this on chrome console. There is an another error in saas(). Refer http://jsfiddle.net/jm6ky/2/ for solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine on my end with a little modification. Unless I don't I understand you.

```
<div id='myModal' class='modal'>
    <div id='modal-content'>
        <span onclick='closeFunc()'>close x</span>
        <object id='pdf-enter' data='' type='application/pdf'><p id='fallback-text'>Your browser does not support this media. You can download it <a id='dl-link' href=''>here.</p></a></object>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='aud'>
    <audio id='paudio' src='../../music/Available Now.mp3' controls='controls' preload="metadata">Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code>element.</audio>
    <p id='audio-metadata'></p>
</div>

. . . 

<li><i onclick='audiosass()' class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-fw" aria-label='Listen to music.'>audiosass</i> <i onclick='openModal(), audiosass()' class='fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-fw' aria-label='View the sheet music.'>open</i>
</li>

<script defer async>

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var here = document.getElementById('dl-link');
var close = document.getElementById('close');
var pdf = document.getElementById('pdf-enter');

function openModal() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}    

function audiosass() {
    pdf.setAttribute('data', '../../scores/Sassthefrass Perusal.pdf');
    here.setAttribute('href', '../../scores/Sassthefrass Perusal.pdf');
}

function closeFunc() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: That is the issue : When I modify the third var to show `getElementByID` instead of `getElementID`, the modal does not open anymore.